# Cannot create a TPU inside of a GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, tpu

So, I created a GCP Compute optimized VM and gave it full access to all cloud apis as well as full HTTP and HTTPS traffic access. I now want to create a TPU from inside this VM i.e. run the following command:

```
gcloud compute tpus create node-1 --zone us-central1-a --project $PROJECT_NAME --version 2.5.0 --accelerator-type v3-8 --no-async
```

and it constantly errors with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'tpu.nodes.create' denied on 'projects/$PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1-a/nodes/node-1'
```

I only ever get this error in the VM, but when I run this command on my local machine with my local install of gcloud, everything works fine. It is really weird because all other commands like gcloud list and gsutil all work fine, but creating TPUs doesn't work. I even tried adding a service account into ~/.credentials and setting that in my bashrc:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/.credentials/service-account.googleapis.com.json
```

but this doesn't solve the problem. I even tried with the execution groups as well:

```
gcloud compute tpus execution-groups create --name=node-1 --zone=us-central1-a --tf-version=2.5.0 --accelerator-type=v3-8 --tpu-only --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

but this also fails.

Comment: Check the scopes assigned to the VM. You will find them near the bottom of the VM Edit screen in the Google Cloud Console GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two possible reasons why you have Permission denied Error:

1. Service Account does not have Allow full access to all Cloud APIs.
2. Account doesn't have a role `TPU ADMIN`.

I tried to create TPU using your command. I got the same error before modifying the service account. Here is the output that TPU has been created.

```
$ gcloud compute tpus create node-1 --zone us-central1-a --project $PROJECT_NAME --version 2.5.0 --accelerator-type v3-8 --no-async \
Create request issued for: [node-1]
Waiting for operation [projects/project-id/locations/us-central1-a/operations/operation-1634780772429-5ced30f39edf6-105ccd39-96d571fa] to complete...done.     
Created tpu [node-1].
```

Try creating the TPU again after following these instructions:

a. Make sure to Enable TPU API

b. Go to VM Instance and `stop/down` VM before editing service account.

c. Refresh VM instance page and click Edit

d. At the bottom of Instance details page Select Compute Engine Service  Account and `Allow full Access to all Cloud APIs` and `Save`.
(As recommended by @John Hanley)

e. On your Instance Page check and note your `Service Account`.

f. Go to IAM page and look for the Service Account and Edit

g. Click `Add Role` and select `TPU ADMIN` and Save

h. Start your VM instance and SSH to Server

i. Run this command

```
gcloud compute tpus create node-1 --zone us-central1-a --project  $PROJECT_NAME --version 2.5.0 --accelerator-type v3-8 --no-async
```

I encountered error at first because there was existing TPU on the same zone I entered. Make sure that your TPU has not been created with the same zone.